# Speed up matching between a sliding window and a list

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sliding-window

I have an odd length window and a array and I need to find the index of the array where the window is centered and matches more. So far I am doing it with the following code. Is it possible to speed up these computations?

```
import numpy as np
import time

def find_best_match_position(lst, window):
    min_corr = np.inf
    best_position = -1

    for i in range(len(lst) - len(window) + 1):
        window_subset = lst[i:i + len(window)]
        corr = np.linalg.norm(window - window_subset)
        if corr < min_corr:
            min_corr = corr
            best_position = i

    return best_position


input_list_len = int(8E+6)
np.random.seed(2)
input_list = np.random.rand(input_list_len)

win_length = 31
np.random.seed(4)
window = np.random.rand(win_length)

gnd_index = 15

half_width = win_length // 2
start = gnd_index - half_width  # Shift start by 1 to the right
end = gnd_index + half_width + 1
input_list[start:end] = window + 0.01 * np.random.rand(win_length)

t = time.time()
print(f'Computed index {find_best_match_position(input_list, window) + half_width}')
t1 = time.time()
print(f'Computation time {(t1 - t) / 60} min')
# Computed index 15
# Computation time 0.6488747239112854 min
```

Comment: Lots of details missing, for example assuming your list is very large (> 1000) and your window length is very small (< 5) and you want to perform several of these calls for different window contents of same length and a static lst: You could consider precomputing an R-Tree containing all "points" (all consecutive numbers in lst with length of the window) and performing a nearest neighbor query.

Comment: You don't have lists, you have arrays.

Comment: I have updated the post. The input array has a large size while the window has relatively small size.

Comment: You tagged "algorithm" but not NumPy. Does that mean you're after algorithmic optimizations resulting in a better complexity class, and aren't interested in just better NumPy usage?

Comment: I am interested in a faster computation of the index. Either NumPy or algorithmic (e.g. data structures or signal processing techniques) improvements are welcome. I am here to learn. So any answer that helps in this direction is highly appreciated. Thanks for addressing all these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is >10 times faster in my testing.

```
def find_best_match_position(lst, window):
    slides = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(lst, len(window))
    norms = np.linalg.norm(window - slides, axis=1)
    return norms.argmin()
```

Even faster and uses less memory:

```
def find_best_match_position(lst, window):
    return sum(
        (lst[i : i-len(window)+1 or None] - w) ** 2
        for i, w in enumerate(window)
    ).argmin()
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is very helpful. I aim looking the second script. Why it is much faster than the script in my post? Can you provide some explanations or the intuition when you made it?

Comment: @Thoth Mine are much faster than yours because I do very little in Python, most of the work is done by large NumPy operations. While my second solution does have a Python loop, it's only over 31 elements, whereas yours is over 8 million elements. I tried the second one partly because the first one runs out memory on the machine where I tried it (it has very little). And partly because I suspected that the simpler operations (array minus single number, and adding arrays) might be faster.

Comment: I am looking closer your second answer, where you iterate on the length of the window. The i is in [0, 31] when the window has length 31. Form this point I lost what is happening. Why you use the or operator? Also, inside the sum operator there is lists of 31 arrays which then are summed. Can you please explain the intuition on constructing this script?

Comment: @Thoth The expression before `or None` is usually negative, in order to leave the last few elements out of the slice. But in the last iteration it's `-0`, which is the same as `0`, and would make the slice empty. The `or None` replaces it with `None`, so the slice goes to the end of the array. Do you understand what the linalg norm computes? It's the square root of a sum of squared values. I just leave out the square root (since it doesn't affect maximaility) and instead of computing one sum after the other, I compute all sums in parallel, one term at a time.

Comment: @Thoth Put differently: think of the 8 million window slices of length 31 as rows of a matrix, so that's 8 million rows and 31 columns. The "normal" way processes one row at a time to compute its norm. My second solution instead processes one *column* at a time.

Comment: Ok for the first case. In the second case, each column has approximately 8M elements, I I can not connect this part with the part of the code where you make `lst[i : i-len(window)+1 or None] - w`. Any additional clarification are highly appreciated.

Comment: If `lst = a,b,c,d,e,f` and `window = x,y,z`, then you have four norms. The first compares x,y,z with a,b,c. The last compares x,y,z with d,e,f. Overall, x gets compared with a to d, while y gets compared with b to e, and z gets compared with c to f. That a to d is the slice for i=0. Etc.

Comment: Thanks. Something last, what is the purpose of `or None` in your last example? Which case satisfies?

Comment: Maybe you overlooked my earlier comment where I explained that?